# Change of intervals for numerical integration?

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

(Question is at the bottom)

Suppose we have an integral
$
\int_c^d f(t) dt
$. We then define a linear function $\lambda$ of $t$ such that if $t$ traverses $[c,d]$, $\lambda(t)$ traverses $[a,b]$:
$$
\lambda(t) = \frac{b-a}{d-c}t + \frac{ad-bc}{d-c}
$$
Now in the integral $\int_a^b f(x) dx$, we make the change of variable $x = \lambda(t)$. **Then $dx = \lambda'(t) dt = (b-a)(d-c)^{-1} dt$ and so we have**
$$
\int_a^b f(x) dx = \frac{b-a}{d-c} \int_c^d f(\lambda(t)) dt
$$

**Here is the question**: Why is $dx = \lambda'(t) dt = (b-a)(d-c)^{-1} dt$? Specifically, the part $dx = \lambda'(t) dt$. I thought that $dx$ was simply a notation saying "we integrate w.r.t $x$" :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of $dt$ as a small (infinitesimal) change in $t$ then the small change in $x$ is $\frac{b-a}{d-c}dx$, which is what it means bt integrating with respect to $x$.